# Help with debugging and fixing errors with SalesForce Mapping Module

Tags: 7, crm

For Drupal SalesForce Suite I am having the follwoing Errors show up in my log messages

When I select from the Drupal Entity Type , Drupal Entity Bundle, and Salesforce Object I get these errors

Notice: Undefined index: salesforce_record_type_default in salesforce_mapping_form_validate() (line 520 of /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/sites/all/modules/salesforce/modules/salesforce_mapping/includes/salesforce_mapping.admin.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: salesforce_record_types_allowed in salesforce_mapping_form_validate() (line 520 of /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/sites/all/modules/salesforce/modules/salesforce_mapping/includes/salesforce_mapping.admin.inc).

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in salesforce_mapping_form_validate() (line 520 of /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/sites/all/modules/salesforce/modules/salesforce_mapping/includes/salesforce_mapping.admin.inc).

For just SalesForce Object I get this additional error

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_type_checkboxes_value() (line 2337 of /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/includes/form.inc).

In the UI I am unable to add more then the initial field, when I click the button to add additional mapping and select my field type, the second row of fields disappears and it logs this error in watchdog

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in salesforce_mapping_form_field_callback() (line 428 of /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/sites/all/modules/salesforce/modules/salesforce_mapping/includes/salesforce_mapping.admin.inc).

Local Environment on XAMPP Mac OS Yosemite/ Drupal 7.34/ SalesForce Module 7.x-3.0-Dev/PHP 5.6

To further update this issue, it will allow me to create a mapping but with only the first row in the mapping table. If I save it and then go back in to edit, when I click "add another field mapping" I get a popup with this error.

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function salesforce_mapping_form_validate() in /x/x/x/x/x/x/web/includes/form.inc on line 1513

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to find an answer to the issues I was having, I did finally get the mapping module to work by downgrading XAMPP and instead of using PHP 5.6 used PHP 5.3, which enabled the Mapping module to begin functioning properly.